# How to implement mouselook in the browser?

Tags: 3d, javascript, webgl, first-person-shooter, browser-based-games

I am currently creating a 3D first-person shooter game in the browser using WebGL. How would I implement [mouselook/free look](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouselook) for such a game?

Comment: Look at THREE.js's implementation of [FirstPersonControls](http://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/src.source/extras/controls/FirstPersonControls.js.html) class. You might also need to lock the pointer in order to freely look around the player. Try this: [Pointer Lock](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pointerlock/intro/). Unfortunately it's not implemented in Opera and IE but WebGL isn't implement in those browsers either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mouselook is now supported in Chrome and Firefox via the W3C [Pointer Lock](http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerlock/) specification. Essentially:

```
document.onmousemove = function (e) {
  document.body.innerHTML = "<div>dx: " + 
    (e.movementX || e.mozMovementX || e.webkitMovementX || 0);
} 

document.body.onclick = document.body.requestPointerLock ||
                        document.body.mozRequestPointerLock ||
                        document.body.webkitRequestPointerLock;
```

A good tutorial article is [Pointer Lock and First Person Shooter Controls](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pointerlock/intro/) on HTML5Rocks.

Comment: The bug must be fixed, because this demo works in firefox now:  http://mdn.github.io/pointer-lock-demo/ If you update your comment, I'll give you an 'up'

Answer (score 1):

Capture `mousemove` Events and use the `screenX` and `screenY` properties of the event object to update camera position (use the delta to the last `screenX` and `screenY` position to get the amount of movement).

If you have some sort of [scenegraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scenegraph), you could build a node-setup like the following:

```
CameraNode (Scene Node)
 |
 +- YawNode (Scene Node)
     |
     +- PitchNode (Scene Node)
         |
         +- Camera (actual Camera Object)
```

Movement in the X-Axis rotates the YawNode and movement in the Y-Axis rotates the PitchNode. The CameraNode will be moved when the player moves.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, and just takes two things.

1. An event handler for the mouse move event.
2. A camera object representing your basic model-view transformation

#### Sample event code

Here's some sample source code for doing the event handling. The system module (which handles all game <--> browser interaction) keeps track of two variables: `lastMousePosition` and `lastMouseDelta`.

To track the camera with the mouse, you just need `lastMouseDelta` which is how you will know how many degrees to rotate frame-to-frame.

```
  var canvas = /* WebGL rendering context */
  canvas.onmousedown = function (event) { me.handleMouseDown(event); };
  canvas.onmouseup   = function (event) { me.handleMouseUp(event);   };
  canvas.onmousemove = function (event) { me.handleMouseMove(event); };

  // snip

  engine.SystemModule.prototype.handleMouseMove = function(event) {
    this.lastMouseDelta = [event.clientX - this.lastMousePosition[0],
                           event.clientY - this.lastMousePosition[1]];
    this.lastMousePosition = [event.clientX, event.clientY];
  };
```

#### Same camera movement code

Here's some sample code for handling the camera rotation. Given the number of pixels the mouse has moved in the X or Y direction, rotate the camera by that many degrees.

```
 /**
   * degrees/pixel
   * @const
   */
  var cameraMouseRotation = 0.5;


  // Mouse movement for camera angle.
  if (sys.isMouseDown()) {
    var positionChange = sys.getLastMousePositionDelta();
    camera.rotateYDegs(cameraMouseRotation * positionChange[0]);
    camera.rotateXDegs(-cameraMouseRotation * positionChange[1]);
  }
```

Later, when you actually go on to render your world, simply generate a model-view matrix from your camera. (Converting the camera's position, yaw, pitch, and roll into vectors you can pass to gluLookAt.) And you should be good to go.